# How to disable filed based on value in oracle forms 10g?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

i want to disable the  deptno  field  if the value is greater then 10. i have tried the below code but its not working

```
WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE
    GO_BLOCK('EMP');
EXECUTE_QUERY;

POST-TEXT-ITEM

DECLARE
 v_state VARCHAR2(5) := GET_ITEM_PROPERTY('emp.deptno', enabled);  
BEGIN  
IF ( nvl(:emp.deptno,0) > 10 AND v_state = 'TRUE' ) THEN
   SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('emp.deptno', enabled, property_false);
ELSIF ( nvl(:emp.deptno,0) <= 10 AND v_state = 'FALSE') THEN
   SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('emp.deptno', enabled, property_true);
END IF;
end;
```

[Navigater Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxDKL.png)

[Form Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2pes.png)

Comment: What is `a.deptno`? Or, should I rather ask, what is `a` in it?

Comment: What trigger did you put that code in?

Comment: @AndyDan On POST-TEXT-ITEM

Comment: @Littlefoot  I have updated my question .Kindly check

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the Form has two Database Block ( namely `a` and `emp` ) with common column name ( `deptno` ). If so, Consider creating a `POST-TEXT-ITEM` trigger on `:a.deptno` field with code :

```
DECLARE
 v_state VARCHAR2(5) := GET_ITEM_PROPERTY('emp.deptno', enabled);  
BEGIN  
IF ( nvl(:cursor_item,0) > 10 AND v_state = 'TRUE' ) THEN
   SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('emp.deptno', enabled, property_false);
ELSIF ( nvl(:cursor_item,0) <= 10 AND v_state = 'FALSE') THEN
   SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('emp.deptno', enabled, property_true);
   SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('emp.deptno', navigable, property_true);
END IF;
```

in order to disable the concerned item after cursor leaves that item. But, don't forget to enable for other cases.

Comment: FRM-41042:No such property for Set_Item_Property.

Comment: certainly there's a property `enabled` exists for `SET_ITEM_PROPERTY`. @Farooq Are you sure that you correctly state that? Btw, Add `SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('emp.deptno', navigable, property_true);` too.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, `POST-TEXT-ITEM` is almost certainly a wrong choice. It will fire when you're in that item and navigate out of it by pressing `TAB` or `ENTER` keys (assuming that "Validation unit" property is set to "Item" or "Default"). But, if you leave it using a mouse - it won't fire.

Looking at code you posted, you first execute query and then want to disable the item. `POST-QUERY` might be a better choice in this situation.

However, I guess you'd need it once again, in `WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM` (or maybe `WHEN-VALIDATE-RECORD`) trigger(s) because `POST-QUERY` will work at form start, but would do nothing when you start changing items' values. As @AndyDan commented (thank you, Andy), `WHEN-NEW-RECORD-INSTANCE` trigger covers situations when you return back to previously queried record without actually querying it (again). As it means that you should reuse the same code, I'd suggest you to put it into a procedure which will then be called from other triggers, as appropriate.

Furthermore, if it is a tabular form (with *many* records displayed), you should be using `SET_ITEM_INSTANCE_PROPERTY` built-in instead. Unfortunately, it doesn't support the `ENABLED` property so you'd have to use `INSERT_ALLOWED` and/or `UPDATE_ALLOWED`.

Finally, read about "Propagation of property changes". When you change the `ENABLED` property, it also affects some other item properties (navigable, updateable, required) which means that once you set `ENABLED` to `FALSE`, setting it back to `TRUE` isn't enough as you'll have to set previously mentioned properties to `TRUE` as well.

As of code itself, I presume that this should do:

```
IF nvl(:emp.deptno, 0) > 10 THEN
   SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('emp.deptno', enabled   , property_false);
ELSE
   -- reset other properties as well! This is just an example, you'd use
   -- properties that this item actually has

   SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('emp.deptno', enabled   , property_true);
   SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('emp.deptno', navigable , property_true);
   SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('emp.deptno', updateable, property_true);
END IF;
```

Comment: I would consider putting it in WHEN-NEW-RECORD-INSTANCE rather than POST-QUERY.  That way it would fire correctly if the user navigates back to a previously-queried record without actually querying it again.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @Andy. That's (partially) covered in my 3rd paragraph which says that the same code should be reused in different triggers. I added your remark to the answer for completeness.